# Detect if the link has video extension (.avi or .mpg etc..) return false

Tags: php

I need to check if this link is a normal page or a video befor passed to file_get_contents

Because if the link is a video the page will wait until get the whole video code

And I don't need the video code anyway

This example of my code

```
//$fooURL = "foofoo.com/page.html";
//$fooURL = "foofoo.com/video.mpg";
//$fooURL = "foofoo.com/video.avi";

if($fooURL == ???){
    echo "This a video not normal page";
}else{
    file_get_contents($fooURL);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
if(preg_match('/.*\.(:?mpg|avi)/', $fooURL)){
    echo "This a video not normal page";
    ...
```

Add the appropriate extensions if necessary: `(:?mpg|avi|mp4)` etc.

Comment: Thank You @user4035 :), Is there any source to get all the extensions for videos and images

Comment: Nevermind I got it :), http://knowledge.kaltura.com/kaltura-simple-uploader-ksu-uiconf-and-file-type-filters

Answer (score 2):

Consider the [finfo_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) function to return the MIME type of the file, then parsing that output with preg_match() to see if it's a video.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, for relative simplicity:

```
switch (strtolower(array_pop(explode('.', $fooURL)))) {
    case 'mpg':
    case 'avi':
    // etc...
       echo "This would be a video link.";
       break;
    case 'html':
    case 'php':
    default:
        echo "This isn't, or doesn't seem to be, a video file.";
        break;
}
```

References:

- [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php).
- [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).
- [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php).
- [`switch` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).